# Given a Tensoflow MetaGraph, how can I find the input tensor and the output tensor of this graph?

Tags: tensorflow, graph

Hi I want to import a MetaGraph like this: https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow-cmake/blob/master/inference/python/inference.py
but I don't know how I can find out the name of the input and output tensors.

I already printed the names for all tensors of the graph, but that doesn't help, since there are thousands of tensors.

Comment: Usually, the provider of the MetaGraph should also indicate the names of the relevant input and output tensors, or put them in some particular graph collection. If you don't have that information, you can try things like looking for operations that have no inputs or no outputs, although the ones that you want might not be among those. Sometimes MetaGraphs include a "signature" indicating the input and output tensors, for example when they are part of a [saved model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model), you could try to see if there is anything in the `signature_def` field...